# Rails 3: how to render text file in-line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, text, rendering, inline

All.

A Rails n00b here...

I'm writing an application that reports the status of a transaction.
Some of the content in the rendered HTML comes from instance variables
initialized in the controller, while other content comes from text files
(e.g., log files) that I want to render in the HTML using `<pre>` tags.

What is the "Rails Way" to do this?

Thank you for your time...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
<pre>
    <%= render :file => '/tmp/test.log' %>
</pre>
```

Comment: You can use <%= simple_format render :file => @file %> for html formatting such as \n => <br/>

Answer (score 3):

Here you go: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Answer (score 0):

In some cases (when the file is not small and loading it is connected with a delay), I prefer to load the page content and then to use `jQuery` ajax request to load the file content.

For example, let's say I have a model with file path attribute. In the `view` layout I am doing something like this:

```
<pre data-source=" <%= (@file.path) %>"></pre>
```

Then in the corresponding `js` file I am loading the context like this:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $.ajax(
    url: $("pre").data("source")
    context: document.body
  ).done (response) ->
    $("pre").html response
    return
  return
```

Of course you can check the [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) documentation for more options. For example, you can render the `pre` tag with `loading` like this:

```
<pre data-source=" <%= (@file.path) %>"><div class="loading"></pre>
```

or use other `jQuery` animations as well.