# Render view as text in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller method, that should simply output a .txt document with some kind of report. I would like to use a erb view for it, so I'm able to do the presentation of the report on the level where it should be.

I'm having difficulties in making Rails behave in this way. I found the `render plain:`, but this does not seem to allow to use a view template.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails 3: how to render text file in-line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6257998/rails-3-how-to-render-text-file-in-line)

Comment: Ehh no it's not...That's about including text files in a view. Not creating a text file with a view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that by just adding a view file like `*.text.erb` and hit that path with `.txt` in the url (e.g. `/users/report.txt`).

Example (tested on Rails 4.2):

**Controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def report
  end
end
```

**View**

```
# app/views/users/report.text.erb
Current time: <%= Time.now %>
```

Now, visit that path (`/users/report.txt`) in your browser:

```
Current time: 2016-09-09 12:16:02 +0200
```

As is in `html` templates, if you define any instance variable in the controller, it would be accessible in the `text` template.